# Please help me understand the meaning of these sentences

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence

The documentary I am watching is about WW2 (wartime Dover, actually).
And the narrator, who is aboard a helicopter, utters these sentences, putting  himself in the shoes of a German airman:

> We know the Luftwaffe bombarded this airfield time and time again.
> Hawkinge was a key part of our defenses.
>
> **Straight over the top. Bombs gone. Have we got ‘em Mike?**

(Mike is the helicopter pilot.)**

I don't understand the sentences in bold.

Comment: It’s not enough context for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I assume, I'm not sure though:

- **Straight over the top.**

Directly on top of the people they are trying to hit.

- **Bombs gone.**

The bombs have been dropped.

- **Have we got ‘em Mike? (Mike is a pilot in a helicopter.)**

Did we get them, Mike?